# Create new Service instance in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any good way to force creating new instance of Angular2's injected Service? Let's say I have SomeService where I set a lot of fields on its creation:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  private initialized: boolean = false;
  private things: Object[] = [];
  private somethingElse: number = 0;

  constructor(protected injectedService: InjectedService) {
    this.initialized = true;
    this.somethingElse = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    this.injectedService.getThings(this.somethingElse)
      .subscribe(things => this.things = things);
  }
}
```

And then i.e. the user logs out and the all data set is no longer valid nor should be present there.
Does Angular2 with Typescript provide any way to destruct current service instance and get new one or do I have to fetch the logout event and clean up all the data manually?

Comment: `let _fake:SomeService = new SomeService()` will clean all

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? If there's a logout method, why doesn't *that* update the state as appropriate?

Comment: @anshuVersatile, it won't clear old service and won't work with DI, I think.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, logout method is in other service that is responsible for authorization. I know I can fetch the event and clean all the data manually, but looking for a better way.

Comment: It might be helpful to quantify *"better"*. What's the *problem* you want to solve?